# Баг TimePickerDialog и DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, xml, datetime, datepicker

Minimum SDK стоит 19 (Kitkat), на устройствах от Lollipop все работает нормально, а на Kitkat почему-то вот такая интересная проблема... В чем может быть дело? Может потому что Dialog всплывает в Fragment?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            CalendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            CalendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(SetTime.this, dialogtheme,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            String resulttime = null;
                            int minlength = Integer.toString(minute).length();
                            int hourlength = Integer.toString(hourOfDay).length();
                            Log.d("mTag", hourOfDay + "");
                            Log.d("mTag", minute + "");
                            if(hourlength == 2 & minlength == 2) {
                                resulttime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                            }
                            else if(hourlength == 1 & minlength == 1) {
                                resulttime = 0 + "" + hourOfDay + ":" + 0 + minute;
                            }
                            else if (hourlength == 2 & minlength == 1){
                                resulttime = hourOfDay + ":" + 0 + minute;
                            }
                            else if (hourlength == 1 & minlength == 2){
                                resulttime = 0 + "" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                            }
                            butto.setText(resulttime);

                        }
                    }, CalendarHour, CalendarMinute, true);
            timepickerdialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело было в установке темы dialogtheme, видимо старый DatePickerDialog это не поддерживает, соответственно возникает вот такая "лишняя рамка"